# Detecting header file while building Python extension

Tags: python, distutils

I have a Python C extension to which I'd like to add optional support for an external header-only library. When a user runs `./setup.py install` (or `pip install`) I'd like to detect whether the C++ compiler can find the header, and if so, define a macro when compiling the extension.

Are there any convenient ways to do this?